# validating radio button

Tags: c#

I am programming in c# and I have some radio buttons in my form, and I want to make validation assuring that the user selected all the radio buttons in the button, so my method is :

```
 public bool check_radiobutton(RadioButton radio1, RadioButton radio2)
        {
            //none of them aare selected
            if ((radio1.Checked) && (radio2.Checked))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You forgot to select a radiobutton!");
            }
            return true;
        }
```

but it did not work

Comment: "it did not work" is a poor problem description. What didn't work? Were there errors? Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: is your logic right? it seems like your returning true and false are reversed.

Comment: You can't select all options in a properly set up radio button. Here you are checking for `A && B` which can never be the case. You should check `A || B` for the user selecting one **or** the other. In the extreme you could check for `!A && !B` as one of them should be checked.

Answer (score 1):

For each pair of radio button you have (or for each set, being it pairs for yes/no questions). You must check if at least (in fact if only) one of the options is checked. That is you want to check if:

```
(radio1.Checked) || (radio2.Checked)
```

Why is it? Because this way you are asking if radio1 is checked or else if radio2 is checked. Otherwise, if you keep:

```
(radio1.Checked) && (radio2.Checked)
```

You are asking if radio1 is checked and also if radio2 is checked. Which can't be, that's like requesting to answer both "yes" and "no". Of course this will never evaluate to true, unless there is something inherentily wrong with the universe.

From your comment:

```
//none of them aare selected
```

I guess you were trying to use D' Morgan's law, which applied to this cases states that:

```
(radio1.Checked) || (radio2.Checked) == !((!radio1.Checked) && (!radio2.Checked))
```

You can read this code:

```
!((!radio1.Checked) && (!radio2.Checked))
```

As follows: If it's false that (radio1 is not checked and also radio2 is not checked). That will be false only if both are not checked, which is the case when you want to return false (that is you want to return true when that evaluates to true):

```
if (!((!radio1.Checked) && (!radio2.Checked)))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

By reversing the if, you end up with:

```
if ((!radio1.Checked) && (!radio2.Checked))
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

Which is close to what you have, but not quite the same thing. So, a proposed implementation for your method would be [I changed your style to mine]:

```
public bool CheckRadioButtons(RadioButton radioButtonA, RadioButton radioButtonB)
{
    //none of them are selected
    if ((!radioButtonA.Checked) && (!radioButtonB.Checked))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You forgot to select a RadioButton!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also, as I think you may want to take out the MessageBox from there you can compress the method to:

```
public bool CheckRadioButtons(RadioButton radioButtonA, RadioButton radioButtonB)
{
    return !((!radioButtonA.Checked) && (!radio2.radioButtonB));
}
```

A generalization would be something like:

```
public bool CheckRadioButtons(params RadioButton[] radioButtons)
{
    foreach (RadioButton radioButton in radioButtons)
    {
        if (radioButton.Checked)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You may still show the messegebox in the caller if you like [Which I think is a good thing separate those concerns]. Also if you are using Linq [Remeber to add "using System.Linq" at the top of yout file or namespace block, avaliable form .NET 3.5]:

```
public bool CheckRadioButtons(params RadioButton[] radioButtons)
{
    return radioButtons.Any(radioButton => radioButton.Checked);
}
```

Given the simplicity of this, you may consider skip to create a method for this altogether. Here is how you may call this with only two RadioButtons without an additional method:

```
(new RadioButton[]{radioButtonA, radioButtonB}).Any(radioButton => radioButton.Checked);
```

Of course it's an overhead for simple cases as the one with only two RadioButtons, so having a method will allow you to overload it for the simple cases (such as 2 RadioButtons and 3 RadioButtons).

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are generally used to represent options which are mutually exclusive. Checkboxes better represent what you seem to need (multiple choices).

If I try to add two radio buttons on a form I see that only one of them can be `checked` (the other is automatically unchecked when I do this).

This means that the two radio buttons will never be `checked` at the same time and the MessageBox will always show...

EDIT:

Only one of the radio buttons inside a container can be `checked` at a time.
You can use this to implement "either A or B" and "either C or D" by having 2 panels, one with radio buttons for A and B and another panel with radio buttons for C and D.

Since it is possible for neither radio button to be checked a valid state is the one where one of the buttons is checked. You don't check this with && (which is AND ) but with || (which is OR).

```
bool IsValid = radio1.Checked || radio2.Checked;
```

Comment: If I have to use checkbox,what should I do to make the user select only one answer of the checkboxes?

Comment: @Sharon: best you don't try, that's what radio buttons are for. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have a form consists of question I'm asking the user, and some of these questions are Yes/No questions which are presented as radio button in the form. However, before getting to the next form I have to validate that no pair of radio buttons are left unchecked by the user.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you check if both the radiobutons are checked, but this will never happen because always on of the radio buttons will be check. You should use checkboxes to make this happen or change the && to || to check that at leased one of the buttons is checked.